# Stored Procedure (rookie programmer), What's wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will update a related row in the `BugIt` table given an expense report number `ErepNo` and expense category number `EXNo`.

The procedure must contain 3 input  parameters `EXNo` ,`ErepNo` and the `'rUpAm'` and with one boolean output parameter `aRes`.

If the `ErepStatus` is equal to '`Approved`' then the stored value `rUpAm` is added to `BIAct`,the output parameter is set to `TRUE` and the row is updated.

Else the `ErepStatus` is equal to '`Denied`' or '`Pending`' an application error is raised and the output parameter is set to `FALSE`.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StoredProcedure1
(tEXNo IN BugIt.EXNo%TYPE,
 tErepNo IN ER.ErepNo%TYPE,
 rUpAm IN INTEGER, 
 aRes OUT BOOLEAN ) IS
FOUND BOOLEAN := False; 
tErepStatus ER.ErepStatus%TYPE;
tBIAct BugIt.BIAct%TYPE;


CURSOR ERCur(TmpErepNo ExpI.ErepNo%TYPE)is
 SELECT ExpI.EXNo, ER.ErepStatus
    FROM ER, BugIt, ExpI
    WHERE ER.ErepNo = tErepNo
      AND BugIt.EXNo = ExpI.EXNo
      AND ER.ErepNo = ExpI.ErepNo
    ORDER BY ErepStatus DESC;
    
BEGIN 
OPEN ERCur(tErepNo);
LOOP
    FETCH ERCur INTO  tErepStatus, tBIAct;
    EXIT WHEN ERCur%NOTFOUND;
    IF tErepStatus = 'APPROVED' THEN
        FOUND := TRUE;
    END IF;
    IF tErepStatus = 'PENDING' OR tErepStatus = 'DENIED' THEN
        FOUND := False;
        EXIT;
    END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE ERCur;
IF FOUND THEN
    tBIAct := tBIAct + rUpAm;
    aRes := TRUE;
    UPDATE BugIt 
    Set BIAct = tBIAct
    WHere EXNo = tEXNo;
          
ElSE 
    tBIAct := tBIAct;
    aRes := False;
END IF;
    
    
    
    
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN aRes := False;
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Database error');
END;    
/
```

Here is my test case to implement the code that I have, which keeps coming up with errors(below)

```
---test--
SET Serveroutput on;

SELECT ExpI.EXNo, ER.ErepStatus
    FROM ER, BugIt, ExpI
    WHERE ER.ErepNo = 21
      AND BugIt.EXNo = ExpI.EXNo
      AND BugIt.ErepNo = ExpI.ErepNo
    ORDER BY ErepStatus DESC;
    
-- Test script
DECLARE
Result BOOLEAN;
aBIAct BugIt.BIAct%TYPE;
BEGIN

StoredProcedure1(2, 2, 3, Result);
IF Result then
    dbms_output.put_line('updated element to the BugIt table');
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Row not updated to the  BugIt table');
END IF;
END;
/


ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Database error
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.SPROLLUPEXPITEM", line 51
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Comment: In `StoredProcedure1` you are catching the errors using `WHEN OTHERS`. Take out the exception handling and call the procedure again to see what error is actually occurring.

Comment: You are also using `TmpErepNo` in the declaration of your cursor, but you do not use it anywhere in the query. If you do not need it, take it out of the cursor declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StoredProcedure1 (
  tEXNo IN BugIt.EXNo%TYPE,
  tErepNo IN ER.ErepNo%TYPE,
  rUpAm IN INTEGER, 
  aRes OUT BOOLEAN
)
IS
  tErepStatus ER.ErepStatus%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT ER.ErepStatus
  INTO   tErepStatus
  FROM   ER
         INNER JOIN ExpI
         ON ( ER.ErepNo = ExpI.ErepNo )
         INNER JOIN BugIt
         ON ( BugIt.EXNo = ExpI.EXNo )
  WHERE  ER.ErepNo = tErepNo
  AND    ER.ErepStatus IN ( 'APPROVED', 'PENDING', 'DENIED' )
  ORDER BY ErepStatus DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
  
  aRes := tErepStatus = 'APPROVED';
  
  IF aRes THEN
    UPDATE BugIt 
    SET   BIAct = BIAct + rUpAm
    WHERE EXNo = tEXNo;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    aRes := FALSE;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ER ( ErepNo, Erepstatus ) AS
SELECT 1, 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'PENDING'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'DENIED'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'APPROVED' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE ExpI ( ErepNo, EXNo ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE BugIt ( EXNo, BIAct ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  aRes BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  StoredProcedure1( 1, 1, 1, aRes );
  IF ares THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Changed' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Not Changed' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Outputs `Changed` and:

```sql
SELECT * FROM BugIt;
```

Gives:

> ```
> EXNO | BIACT
> ---: | ----:
>    1 |     2
>    2 |     2
>    3 |     3
> ```

And:

```sql
DECLARE
  aRes BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  StoredProcedure1( 3, 3, 1, aRes );
  IF ares THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Changed' );
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Not Changed' );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Outputs `Not Changed` and the `BugIt` table has not changed.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=08bfe1f10fdc21e2dff1312fcb3e09cf)*